# Python Pandas - PostgreSQL: Speed-up the loop for more efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, performance, time-complexity

I have the following python code that parsers multiple data frames and sends the row value to postgreSQL DB. I am first establishing a connection to postgreSQL and then using the cursor to execute my query. I need to run this loop for a minimum of 100,000 per run. (The number may increase but not decrease, hence need an efficient solution)

Here the requirement is to send each row of the DB one after the other and also send these rows in the sequence given below(this is the basic structure, the actual number of levels is far more than this), hence cannot use execute_many option.

```
For Every customer:
            1. Customer Table 1
            2. Customer Table 2
            3. Customer Table 3
            4. For Each contact:
                1. Contact Table 1
                2. Contact Table 2
            5. For each account:
                1. ACCOUNT Table 1
                2. ACCOUNT Table 2
                3. ACCOUNT Table 3
                4. ACCOUNT Table 4
                For each product under the account:
                    1. Product Table 1
                    2. Product Table 2
                    3. Product Table 3
                    4. Product Table 4
```

Below is my current code:

```
def generate_values_for_insert_statement(df, index):
        values = []
        if isinstance(df.loc[index], pd.core.series.Series):
            values.append(df.loc[index].to_list())
        else:
            for row in df.loc[index].values:
                values.append(list(row))
        return values

for customer in customer_df.index.to_list():
            ### CUSTOMER Table ###
            values = customer_df.loc[customer].to_list()
            cursor.execute(customer_sql, values)

            ### Customer Table 2 ###
            values = generate_values_for_insert_statement(
                customer_df_2, customer)
            for value in values:
                cursor.execute(customer_sql2, value)
            ### customer Table 3 ###
            values = generate_values_for_insert_statement(
                customer_df3, customer)
            for value in values:
                cursor.execute(customer_sql_3, value)

            ### CONTACT table ###
            for customer, contact in contact_df.loc[[customer]].index:
                value = (contact_df.loc[customer, contact].to_list())
                cursor.execute(contact_sql, value)

                ### contact Table 2 ###
                value = (
                    contact_df2.loc[customer, contact].to_list())
                cursor.execute(contact_sql_2, value)

            ### ACCOUNT Table ###
            for customer, account in accounts_df.loc[[customer]].index:
                value = (accounts_df.loc[customer, account].to_list())
                cursor.execute(account_sql, value)

                ### acconut Table 2 ###
                value = (
                    account_df_2.loc[customer, account].to_list())
                
                cursor.execute(account_sql_2, value)

                ### Account Table 3 ###
                for row in account_df_3.loc[(customer, account)].values:
                    cursor.execute(account_sql_3, row)

                ### Product Table 1 ###
                for customer, account_id, product_seq in products_df.loc[[customer]].index:
                    value = (
                        products_df.loc[customer, account, product_seq].to_list())
                    cursor.execute(product_sql, value)
                    ### Product Table 2 ###
                    value = product_df_2.loc[(
                        customer, account, product_seq)].to_list()
                    cursor.execute(product_sql_2, value)
                    ### Product Table 3 ###
                    
                    value = product_df_3.loc[(
                        customer, account, product_seq)].to_list()
                    cursor.execute(product_sql_3, value)
```

Comment: Is the table nesting you are  showing following FOREIGN KEY relationships? In other words as example are `contacts` rows  children of `customer` rows?

Comment: yes thats true.

Comment: Then why not populate all the customer tables first using `execute_batch` or `execute_values`(not `execute_many` per [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)) or [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). Then populate the child tables(`contacts`). Same for `account` then `product` tables.

Comment: I have to populate one after the other. that is my requirement.